# Laravel complex unique validation brain teaser

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I got a task on new job, and can't figure out the solution that works, and also is there a possible way to do this.

In my cms application I created option for adding pages. Pages can be added for multiple languages. So in my database I have two tables:

```
pages
id, is_default, page_parent, published, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at

page_translations
id, page_id, content, slug, locale
```

(where locale is language prefix(en, fr, de ...))

So, on create page, you need to fill title and content for each language that you have.

The admin user should not be able to create two pages with the same title, so I created a rules:

```
private function generateRules() {
    foreach (\App\Models\SiteLanguages::all() as $language) {
        $page = $this->getPageInfoFromRequestByLanguage($language);
        $rules[$language->code. '.title'] = 'required|unique:page_translations,title,' . $this->generateRuleAppendix($page);
    }
    return $rules;
}


private function getPageInfoFromRequestByLanguage($language) {
    return $this->get($language->code);
}


private function weAreEditingPage($page) {
    return key_exists('id', $page);
}

private function generateRuleAppendix($page) {
    $append = '';
    if ($this->weAreEditingPage($page)) {
        $append = ',' . $page['id'];
    }
    return $append;
}
```

Essentially, what this piece of code is doing is checking page we are editing, and setting the title to be unique. The problem is that, ok, it is working, you can't add page with the same name, but, it also wont edit the page if the title field is the same for other language title.

So if I edit the page and set the title name for *en: Test*, and title for *fr: Test*, the page will not edit because of the unique rule.

I need a way to be able to update title on editing for all languages, and those field can be the same, but It cannot be the two pages with same name.

Answer (score -1):

I guess there is typo in your code

```
    private function generateRules() {
        foreach (\App\Models\SiteLanguages::all() as $language) {
            $page = $this->getPageInfoFromRequestByLanguage($language);
            $rules[$language->code. '.title'] = 
'required|unique:page_translations,title,' . $this->generateRuleAppendix($page);
        }
        return $rules;
    }
```

The typo is in here

... unique:page_translations,title,' . $this->...

an extra comma inside quote, try removing it and check it again if it is working